# why some code calls request_threaded_irq with NULL as a parameter for irq_handler?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

As per kernel docs, `request_threaded_irq` is used to split it in two parts, irq_handler checks whether the interrupt originates from the device. If yes it needs to disable the interrupt on the device and return `IRQ_WAKE_THREAD` which will wake up the handler thread and run `@thread_fn`.

But I found some code register interrupt, using `request_threaded_irq` while passing `NULL` as `irq_handler` and they keep complete functionality in `thread_fn`.

So my doubt is why we use `request_threaded_irq()` in that case, while we can easily use `request_irq`, which behaves same for the mentioned scenario.

Comment: `request_irq` is created first and then `request_threaded_irq` . While `request_irq` in modern kernel are wrapped by `request_threaded_irq` with `thread_fn` as `NULL` for compatiblility. See [interrupt.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/interrupt.h#L157).

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-request-threaded-irq.html) says:

> If NULL and thread_fn != NULL the default primary handler is installed

The default primary handler is undocumented, but its source should be self-explaining:

```c
 static irqreturn_t irq_default_primary_handler(int irq, void *dev_id)
 {
         return IRQ_WAKE_THREAD;
 }
```

Comment: in that case isn't it the same thing as request_irq? As interrupt is enabled only you are asking thread_fn to run.

Comment: @Rahul, at least, there is a difference in the context where the real handler runs (process VS hard IRQ), which is the main point of threaded IRQ handlers, by the way.